# Is there an up to date guide on PHP (5.3) Apache (2) and FastCGI?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos, fastcgi

All the articles I can find on the web all are dated from 2005 - 2009.  We are looking to move to fastcgi with php and apache but can't find any up to date information on the topics.  Does anyone know of a good guide or why the information just kind of falls off?  We're running Cent OS 5 for our boxes.

Comment: Maybe the information you found is still valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example this guide http://howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-apache2-with-mod_fcgid-and-php5-on-centos-5.2 is very good but the wrapper script **php-fcgi-starter**

```
#!/bin/sh
PHPRC=/etc/
export PHPRC
export PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=5000
export PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN=8
exec /usr/bin/php-cgi
```

is to aggressive.

In mine case, I had to set PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN to 0 and PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS to 500.